# automatically set alarm clock on iPhone if calendar event

Tags: iphone, calendar, google-calendar, automation

Is there any way to automatically set the alarm clock on my iPhone if my calendar has an event in the morning?  The calendar events are being added from a variety of platforms via Google calendar, and I'd like there to automatically be an alarm on the phone (if the event is in the morning.)

Thanks

Comment: and this did not help https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?hl=en ?

Comment: To clarify (for me) it is not a repeating event! it is new event that get made by someone else and it shows up on your Google Calendar (and in your iCal).  It originally does not contains alarm or notification setting. As for morning? what specific time are you looking for (like before 9 AM or ?)

Comment: this might work for you https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/calarm-calendar-alarm-clock/id509840570?mt=8

Comment: @Buscar웃 you understood in your second comment, and appear to have provided an excellent answer in your third.

Comment: So it works for you then :) let me make this a full answer for others to find the solution :)

Comment: cheers to that!

Comment: Have any of you tried the app? I see no reviews for it. If it works as advertised, I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a app on iTunes that might do just what you want.

[Calarm: Calendar Alarm Clock](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/calarm-calendar-alarm-clock/id509840570?mt=8)
By squishLogic

For $1 it is worth trying.

This app will automatically wake you up every day before your first calendar event and alert you about events during the day.

•

```
Alarms for all calendar events, including all-day and birthdays
• Ability to cancel specific alarms
• Ability to mute specific alarms
• Ability to change alert time for specific alarms
• Quick alarms - great for naps
• Send Quick alarms as a reminder to a friend
• No need to customize events
• No need to open the calendar app
• Select which calendars make alarms
• Adjustable wake up time
• Separate time interval for daytime events
• Reads calendar app, so no internet connection is needed
• Snooze any event
• 5-15 minute adjustable snooze interval
• Shows event on the lock screen with time until event and location
• Confirmation tab listing all scheduled alarms for the week
• View that shows events for a given day
• Control alarms for busy or free events
• 20 different alarm sounds
• Set up behaviors to better customize to your needs
• 12/24 hour clock
• Control event behavior from notes
• See alarm location, time, end time, and calendar
• Alarms can be defaulted to on, off, or muted
• Alarms can be set to sound until you dismiss them
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the alarm has to be activated on the event itself in your calendar app.

Just go to the event and edit it, then set a reminder alarm to go off at a specified time before the event (15 min. before, 1 hr. before, etc.).

Remember, you can set alarms when you're creating the event as well. =)

Comment: Thanks @APC-Patrick.  I updated my question to more accurately reflect my needs here.